# Не выполняется вывод текста

Tags: php

```
<?php
$put = $_POST['file'];
$file = fopen("$put","r");
$linesCnt = 0;
if(!file)
  {
    echo("Ошибка открытия файла");
  }
    else
  {

    $num_str =  0; 
    while (!feof($file))
    {
        fgets($file);
        $num_str++;
    }
    echo " <br /> Kolvo strok ($num_str)";
    echo " <br /> soderzanie faila: <br />";
    echo @fread($file,filesize("$put"));
    fclose($file);
}

?>
```

Не выполняется часть:

```
echo @fread($file,filesize("$put"));
        fclose($file);
```

Не могу понять почему.

Comment: Уберите собачку и вам выведется ошибка :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы через fgets в цикле читаете весь файл. Курсор чтения при этом оказывается в конце файла. Затем fread естественно вызовет ошибку, так как файл уже весь прочтён. Целесообразно написать так:

```
<?
$put = $_POST['file'];
$file = fopen("$put","r");
$linesCnt = 0;
if(!$file)
  {
    echo("Ошибка открытия файла");
  }
    else
  {

    $num_str =  0; $strfile = "";
    while (!feof($file))
    {
        $strfile .= fgets($file);
        $num_str++;
    }
    echo " <br /> Kolvo strok ($num_str)";
    echo " <br /> soderzanie faila: <br />";
    echo $strfile;
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Comment: При таком варианте и память меньше засоряться будет верно?

Comment: Просто хотелось бы установить ini_set('memory_limit', '128M'); его я установил, осталось понять как сделать, чтобы этот пример память не забивал.

Comment: Память меньше забиваться будет при таком варианте:

    echo " <br /> soderzanie faila: <br />";
    $num_str =  0;
    while (!feof($file))
    {
        echo fgets($file);
        $num_str++;
    }
    echo " <br /> Kolvo strok ($num_str)";

Answer (score 1):

Перед этой частью поставьте

```
rewind ($file); // или fseek($file, 0);
```

Вы пытаетесь читать данные, когда указатель в конце файла стоит.

Answer (score 1):

`if(!file)` <- это опечатка, надеюсь?

`echo @fread($file,filesize("$put"));` <- бред какой.
Вы же уже прочитали файл. Сделайте "буфер" при чтении, затем просто выведите его:

```
$buf = '';
while (!feof($file))
    {
        $buf .= fgets($file);
        $num_str++;
    }

    echo " <br /> Kolvo strok ($num_str)";
    echo " <br /> soderzanie faila: <br />";
    echo $buf;
    fclose($file);
```